# bad operand type actionlistener for unary operator exclamation mark

Tags: java, netbeans, operators, actionlistener

I am getting a "bad operand type actionlistener for unary operator !" error on line 2, as well as error "incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to ActionListener on lines 2 and 8. I also have an error on line 5 at the .start() stating that a the symbol start cannot be found. Does anyone know what went wrong here?

```
private void walkjButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if(!walk){ //error here
        walk = true; //here
        timer = new Timer(40, walk);
        walk.start(); //here
    }
    else{
        timer.stop();
        walk = false; //and here      
    }
}                                           

private ActionListener walk = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(leftLegWalk){
            while (leftLegLength <=50){
                leftLegLength -= 5;
                }
            while (leftLegLength >=20) {
                    leftLegLength +=5;
                }
            }
        else {
            while (rightLegLength <=50) {
                rightLegLength -=5;
                }
            while (rightLegLength >=20) {
                rightLegLength += 5;
                }
            }
        }
    };

boolean running = false;
int count = 0; 
boolean wave = true;
boolean leftLegWalk = true;
boolean rightLegWalk = false;
int leftLegLength = 50;
int rightLegLength = 50;
private Timer timer;
```

Comment: This looks like Java, not C++

Comment: @CoryKramer tagging error, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up your variables. The variable `walk` is an `ActionListener`. You cannot treat it as a `boolean` (testing its truth value with `if`, assigning `true` or `false`) or as a `Thread` (calling `start()`). It's hard to know for sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I think what you want is:

```
private void walkjButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if(!running){
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(40, walk);
        timer.start();
    }
    else{
        timer.stop();
        running = false;
    }
}
```